# Adding variables to a form post url with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my website there is a form a new user will have to fill out and then after a text message will be sent to the user. This is how the form action looks

```
http://example.com/app_api.php?view=send_sms&amp;&amp;user=username&amp;&amp;pass=password&amp;&amp;message=hello+there+welcome+to+our+group&amp;&amp;sender_id=example&amp;&amp;to=00000000&amp;&amp;key=4
```

But since every user's phone number is different, i want to replace the `to` variable in the form action with the one the user will input in the textfield `phone`

can anyone help me through

```
<form id="new_member_sms" name="new_member_sms" method="post" action="http://example.com/app_api.php?view=send_sms&amp;&amp;user=username&amp;&amp;pass=password&amp;&amp;message=hello+there+welcome+to+our+group&amp;&amp;sender_id=example&amp;&amp;to=00000000&amp;&amp;key=4">
  <label for="phone"></label>
  <blockquote>
    <p>
      <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" />

    </p>
  </blockquote>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty trippy form with sends via POST and also includes GET variables via the action's query string, but here's a quick jquery solution for replacing the phone number in the query string:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#new_member_sms').submit(function(){
    var formAction = $(this).attr('action');
    var newAction = formAction.replace('00000000', $('#phone').val());
    $(this).attr('action', newAction);
});
</script>
```